# Passing string with a double-quote inside it in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently making a discord bot for a friend. The goal of the bot is to manage a RP server, and it need to be able to create players sheet.
To set one of his ability scores, story, name, etc... a user need to use a specific command `!set` that's followed by a list of flags in the following way:

`!set name="Name" strength=10 story="Lorem Ispum" [...]`

I need to have the double quotes in the flags for the story and the name, since it can contain an non-fixed number of words, and the parser of the args would put them in different boxes, which i do not want.

The thing is, when i use the double-quotes in the flags, i get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.UnexpectedQuoteError: Unexpected quote mark, '"', in non-quoted string
```

Is there any way to ignore this?

If it helps, I'm using python 3.8.

Here's what i tried:

- Using single quotes instead of double quotes => Parser does not reconise 'lorem ipsum' as a single string
- Using \" => Same as before
- surrounding my flag with another set of double quotes, and marking the inner ones with \ => It works, but i want to make the bot as easy as possible to use, and i find this solution a bit to heavy on the user part.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76756755/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Nice @Woodford, though I imagine after using this 'trick' the OP will have to parse the unique args variable to separate name and story (which should be easy, for example with a regex: `r'name="([^"]*)" +story="([^"]*)` should work if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: It worked thanks a lot! Just had to do a bit of regex magic thanks to @Swifty and it was done!